# How to force eloquent to accept 'ID' instead of 'id' when saving or updating a record in database?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, sql-server-2008-r2

in laravel, eloquent assumes primary key to be 'id', however, I'm forced to use an already existing database that has 'ID' as a primary key, as a result, the functions save() and update() are not updating the database records.
The question is how do I force eloquent to use 'ID'as the primary key?

I've already tried :

```
protected $primarykey = 'ID';
```

but still with no luck.
However when i change the database column name to 'id' the save() and update() functions works just fine, but this is not a solution that I can use in my case as the database is controlled by the company I'm working for.

Comment: It's `protected $primaryKey = 'ID';` instead of `protected $primarykey = 'ID';`.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir thank you for answering, it works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variable names are case sensitive and the `$primaryKey` property has a capital `K`. Try changing this in your model.

```
protected $primaryKey = 'ID';
```

Comment: @AliOcta If an answer helped you, please consider upvoting and accepting it.

Comment: @TimLewis this is a new account so I can't upvote yet, however, I've accepted the answer.